# How to capture id size photo with webcam using python

Tags: python, webcam, image-size

I have this few lines code which capture images using webcam but the pictures width and  heigth is large.Is it a way i can
have the frame to be small to capture images as the size of passport picture.

Is the any available resource I can use to achieve that .This is how I want my frame to look like so I can use the webcam to capture the images from the head to shoulders.

[image: Image in web]
[image: Final result should look like this]

Example image is attached

```
import cv2

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    try:
        check, frame = webcam.read()
        print(check)  # prints true as long as the webcam is running
        print(frame)  # prints matrix values of each framecd
        cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('s'):
            cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img.jpg', img=frame)
            webcam.release()
            img_new = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            img_new = cv2.imshow("Captured Image", img_new) # SHOWS THE IMAGE AFTER CAPTURING
            cv2.waitKey(1650)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            print("captured images saved")

            break
        elif key == ord('q'):
            print("Turning off camera.")
            webcam.release()
            print("Camera off.")
            print("Program ended.")
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print("Turning off camera.")
        webcam.release()
        print("Camera off.")
        print("Program ended.")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Capture your image and crop to the size and aspect ratio that you want.

Comment: @fmw42 Please help me out am struggling to achieve that

Comment: Provide an example input and the size or w/h aspect ratio that you want.

Comment: @fmw42 I want in this aspect ratio  ``(2 x 2")  or (3.5 x 4.5 cm).``

Comment: pixels and centimeters/inches have no meaningful relation to each other. you don't know about "dpi" anyway.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz 'dpi' is ink contain in an image

Comment: `@O JOE`. How big is the image you grab?  Those are inches sizes and are only relevant to printing.  How big do you want them in pixels -- as large as can be cropped from your input?  Those are w/h aspect ratios of 1:1 and 3.5:4.5 which is good for pixels. However, I need to know how big your input will be and how you want it cropped -- to fill as much of the image or some limiting size.  Alternately, given the inches, I would need to know the printing DPI you will use to achieve those dimensions.  I note that one of your sizes is in inches and the other in cm.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @fmw42 640 x 480 is image  dimension when I capture it with my webcam.  I want something like 200 x 200 to be crop from the picture

Comment: @fmw42 i will use 600 X 600 dpi, for the inches and centimeter you can use any of them

Comment: I assume you are capturing in portrait mode, so I assume you really meant 480x640 (wxh)

Comment: @fmw42 sure in portrait mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to crop to 2in x 2in using Python/PIL. We need to use PIL in order to set the density.  I do not believe that OpenCV allows that. I assume that you want to crop in the center. If not, and for example from the top, let me know. But that will likely crop off the chin.

Unless you have an interactive system that allows a crop location/size specification, you cannot account for every picture, i.e., how big the person will be in the frame. So you also may not know where the head is.

Input (assumed fixed 480x640 portrait mode size):

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# read the input
# https://photogov.com/documents/bs-passport-480x640-photo/
img = Image.open('portrait.jpg')

# get dimensions (assume 480x640)
width, height = img.size

# for 2in x 2in printed result, we want to crop an aspect ratio of 1:1 in center
# so since the height will be larger than the width, we use the width for both dimensions
w2 = xcent = width//2
h2 = ycent = height//2
top = ycent - w2
left = xcent - w2
bottom = ycent + w2
right = xcent + w2

# crop input
crop = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

# get crop size
wd, ht = crop.size

# save image with density appropriate for 2in x 2in print
xprint = 2
yprint = 2
xdensity = wd//xprint
ydensity = ht//yprint
crop.save('portrait_2in_x_2in.jpg', dpi=(xdensity, ydensity))

# show cropped Image
crop.show()
```

Cropped Result:

[image]

Comment: @Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent code for the case of 3.5cm x 4.5cm print output in Python/PIL

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# read the input
# https://photogov.com/documents/bs-passport-480x640-photo/
img = Image.open('portrait.jpg')

# get dimensions (assume 480x640)
width, height = img.size

# compute input height/width ratio, which is 640/480 = 1.3333
in_ratio = height/width

# for 3.5 cm x 4.5 cm printed result, we want to crop an aspect ratio of 3.5:4.5 in center,
# which is a height/width ratio of 4.5/3.5 = 1.2857
out_ratio = 4.5/3.5

# test if in ratio is larger than out ratio
if in_ratio > out_ratio:
    # so if the input aspect ratio is larger than the output ratio, 
    # we use the width of the input as the output and compute the height
    # from the aspect ratios
    w2 = xcent = width//2
    h2 = ycent = height//2
    top = ycent - h2*out_ratio/in_ratio
    left = xcent - w2
    bottom = ycent + h2*out_ratio/in_ratio
    right = xcent + w2
else:
    print("Error: input aspect ratio is not larger than output aspect ratio")
    print("Aborting")
    os.abort()

# crop input
crop = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

# get crop size
wd, ht = crop.size

# save image with density appropriate for 3.5 cm x 4.5 cm print
# convert sizes to inches
xprint = 3.5/2.54
yprint = 4.5/2.54
xdensity = wd//xprint
ydensity = ht//yprint
crop.save('portrait_3p5cm_x_3p5cm.jpg', dpi=(xdensity, ydensity))

# show cropped Image
crop.show()
```

Cropped Result:

[image]

Comment: those two answers merely differ slightly in the calculation of the area to crop. I see no reason to post two answers in this case.

Comment: I created them on different days. I did not want to confuse the images.  But yes, probably better as one.